# Not able to pip install DAG package in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am getting an error while trying pip install DAG packcage.

Error

```
Collecting DAG
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/92/ffc722ac557e3c180f8ec6cdad96d2731b981677529c263c3df04a656910/DAG-0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ASHOK~1.EAP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4dybsujd\DAG\setup.py", line 1, in <module>
        from ez_setup import use_setuptools
      File "C:\Users\ASHOK~1.EAP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4dybsujd\DAG\ez_setup.py", line 94
        except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ASHOK~1.EAP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4dybsujd\DAG\
```

How to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install py-dag`, this will use https://github.com/thieman/py-dag

Answer (score 0):

[DAG](https://pypi.org/project/DAG/), released in 2007. The code is Python2-only.

Try installing the module with Python 2.7. Or find a different, Python3-compatible module.